# How to send an string to a python Rest service in bytes from Java?

Tags: java, python, rest

I have an byte array, and I want to send it to a rest service developed on python.

```
String data = new String(dataInByteArray, "ISO-8859-1");
```

When it arrives to the Rest service, and I print the content from server, it shows

```
b'"data_received"'
```

My problem is when I send the String and it arrives with the quotation marks.

How can I send from Java the byte array, decoded in `ISO-8895-1` or an string that the Rest don't find any quotation marks in the bytes received?

Comment: what is the value of 'data' in java?

Comment: Is the content from a PDF417 barcode